# Python Pandas Group by ALL columns

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I am doing testing for multiple tables with about 40+ columns and I would need to run a group by command for each individual column. Is there a way to simplify this?

Comment: `df.groupby([*df])`. But please provide a [mcve] so we can provide a full solution, or find the appropriate duplicate post with the answer.

Answer (score 0):

For more control over the process (ie. if you want to name each outcome of your grouping test) you can use `df.groupby()` inside a `for` loop iterating over all columns.

A minimal reproducible example would be still be appreciated.

UPDATE: Details may vary, but I would do like this, in order to store each grouped object in a dictionary where keys are the column names:

```
cols = df.columns.values.tolist()
results = {}
for col in cols:
    results[col] = df.groupby([col])
#End
```

However, be aware that this operation will produce `pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy` objects, which are not dataframes.

Comment: Hi Fabio -- Thanks! Could you provide more syntax? df.groupby(for i in df)

Comment: See the update above. And please provide an example.